# Is "I would like you to help me with understanding this." right? Then, how is it different from "I would like you to help me understand this."

Tags: sentence-construction

Is the sentence below correct?

> I would like you to **help me with understanding this**.

If it is right, then how is it different from the sentence below?

> I would like you to **help me understand this**.

Thank you for your help very much.
Any explanations will be appreciated.

Comment: The second one sounds more direct and the first one sounds more "polite" and "formal" *because* it's a little less direct. That is, in the first one, I would feel like the emphasis is on "understanding" while in the second, the emphasis would be on "me."

Comment: @TeacherKSHuang Thanks. And do both express the exact, same meaning?

Comment: Let me put it this way: Either way, I think you would receive help, but are they exactly the same? No, I wouldn't say so.

Comment: @TeacherKSHuang Do you mean they are only different in how respectful it sounds?

Comment: Yes, exactly.........(sorry, just trying to hit the character minimum).

Comment: @TeacherKSHuang Is there any way that the second sentence could sound rude a little, whereas the second doesn't at all?

Comment: Hmmm, personally, I feel like anything could be construed as rude depending on context, tone of voice and, of course, the other person's own perception. What do you think? Had you heard the first one used in a context where you felt like it had been a little rude?

Comment: @TeacherKSHuang As I live in a non-English-used country, there are not many chances for me to hear English. So I cannot answer that, but I appreciate your help. :)

Comment: I see. I had thought it had been a contextual question, but I see now that you had only meant it hypothetically.

Comment: @TeacherKSHuang Yes, you got me. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am answering my own question. As Teacher KSHuang answered with the comments above, the two have almost the same meaning.

The only difference of the first sentence from the second is that it sounds a little bit more "polite" and "formal", as it states the request in a more indirect way. On the other hand, as for the second sentence, it is in more direct form so that it doesn't sound as "polite" and "formal".